# How to import javascript in rails with asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

in my app I have one controller supporting a quite complex object that has a lot of javascript, written in coffescript.

I would like to arrange the javascript on several separate files so to have the code arranged more nicely, although I can't figure out how to import these extra files.

for example I have the file `app/assets/javascripts/general_functions.js.coffee` containing the following:

```
# rounds a number
roundNumber = (rnum, rlength = 5) ->
  pow = Math.pow( 10, rlength )
  newnumber = Math.round(rnum*pow)/pow
  parseFloat(newnumber)

# floors a number
floorNumber = (rnum, rlength = 5) ->
  pow = Math.pow( 10, rlength )
  newnumber = Math.floor(rnum*pow)/pow
  parseFloat(newnumber)

# returns true if the str ends with suffix
endsWith = (str, suffix) ->
  str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !=   -1

# returns the absolute value of a number (always >= 0)
abs = (num) -> 
  if num < 0 then - num else num
```

How do I import it in my `app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee` that needs these functions?

I've tried with adding

```
//= require general_functions
```

to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, with no success

any ideas?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *no success* I'm guessing that the browser is telling you that none of your `general_functions.js.coffee` functions exist and you're getting errors like:

> ReferenceError: roundNumber is not defined

You have a simple scoping issue. The compiled version of CoffeeScript files are wrapped in a self-executing function to prevent namespace pollution so this:

```
roundNumber = (rnum, rlength = 5) ->
  pow = Math.pow( 10, rlength )
  newnumber = Math.round(rnum*pow)/pow
  parseFloat(newnumber)
```

looks like this when it gets to the browser:

```
(function() {
  var roundNumber;
  roundNumber = function(rnum, rlength) {
    // ...
  };
})();
```

and all the functions you've defined are hidden. If you want your functions to be global, then define them as `window` properties:

```
window.roundNumber = (rnum, rlength = 5) ->
  # ...
```

Or better, you can create an application-specific namespace somewhere before the main (Coffee|Java)Script is loaded:

```
app = { }
```

and put your functions in there:

```
app.roundNumber = (rnum, rlength = 5) ->
  # ...
```

Comment: I think you got the right point. How would you create the namespace?

Comment: @dongiulio: You could simply add a `var whatever_your_namespace_is_called = { };` to the top of your `application.js`, anything in there that isn't a comment should get copied through to the final JavaScript blob. You could also put that declaration in your layout (before you pull in the JavaScript) or another JavaScript file that you pull into `application.js` before anything else but I think tossing it right into `application.js` is probably the easiest.

Comment: Thanks, I added the `var app = {};` line just after the jquery inclusion and it all seems to work now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript should be automatically included in your rails application, every controller has its own js file. Using the instructions below will include them.

Your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee` should have this line included:

```
#= require_tree .
```

Or `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` (plain javascript):

```
//= require_tree .
```

When you are viewing your page's source in your browser you should see something like:

```
<script src="/assets/projects.js?body=1"></script>
```

What you are describing is a helper or more global js file with generic features. You could add these to the application.js. Moreover, using a structure like below will include vendor/assets/javascripts/some_generic_feature.js(.coffee)

```
//= require some_generic_feature
```

Answer (score 0):

In `application.js` add both files in the correct order:

*application.js*

```
//= require general_functions
//= require projects
```

Hope this helps!